# MochaJS and Chai test dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to generate some assertions to test my Restful CRUD API but I am not how to test new generated documents. I am using Express + Firebase also, so I was able to test easily users since the ID is the email itself. But in the case of any other documents the IDs are being created randomly.

For example, my user test looks like this:

```js
    describe('POST - /api/admin/users', () => {
        it('Should create a user', done => {
            const user: IUser = {
                name: 'User TDD Test',
                email: 'tdd@test.com',
                password: '123456',
                createdAt: 1585848131576
            };

            chai.request(server)
                .post('/api/admin/users')
                .send(user)
                .end((err, response) => {
                    response.should.have.status(201);
                    response.body.should.be.an.instanceOf(Object);
                    response.body.should.have.property('message').eq('User created');
                    response.body.should.have.property('data')
                        .and.be.an.instanceOf(Object)
                        .and.have.property('name').eq('UserTDD Test');
                    response.body.should.have.property('ok').eq(true);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });

    describe('PUT - /api/admin/users/:email', () => {
        it('Should update a user', done => {
            const email = 'tdd@test.com'
            const user: object = {
                password: '1234567',
                updatedAt: 1585848131576
            };

            chai.request(server)
                .put('/api/admin/users/' + email)
                .send(user)
                .end((err, response) => {
                    response.should.have.status(201);
                    response.body.should.be.an.instanceOf(Object);
                    response.body.should.have.property('message').eq('User updated');
                    response.body.should.have.property('data').eq(null);
                    response.body.should.have.property('ok').eq(true);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
```

Here it's easy to update the same document since they share the same email. But, for example, if I want to update any other collection with a generated ID I won't able to test creation and updates the same way, right?

For example, if I have the same code for a collection "tickets":

```js
describe('POST - /api/admin/tickets', () => {
        it('Should create a ticket', done => {
            const ticket: ITicket = {
                owner: 'tdd@test.com',
                status: 'Open',
                createdAt: 1585848131576
            };

            chai.request(server)
                .post('/api/admin/tickets')
                .send(ticket)
                .end((err, response) => {
                    response.should.have.status(201);
                    response.body.should.be.an.instanceOf(Object);
                    response.body.should.have.property('message').eq('Created ticket');
                    response.body.should.have.property('data')
                        .and.be.an.instanceOf(Object)
                        .and.have.property('owner').eq('tdd@test.com');
                    response.body.should.have.property('ok').eq(true);
                    done();
                });
        });
   });
```

Then, the previous generated ticket has an ID property with an unknown value, so, should I test "PUT method" for a different ticket with a known ID?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: You will have to edit all of my questions since I added those gently greetings in each one of them. No one ever reported my for adding them.

Comment: I will try to get around to it, though it is a fool's errand here. If you can at least write more succinctly for your future questions, volunteer editors will greatly appreciate it! There are not nearly enough of us to go around with the volume of material that comes in. People are not "reported" for chatty material as such, but there are plenty of references on Meta about the desire for succinct and technical writing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a solution but a workaround. I think this is not even a good practice, but it works.

First I added `NODE_ENV=test` to the environment variables when testing:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev src/app.ts",
    "start": "node dist/app.js",
    "test": "env NODE_ENV=test TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"tsconfig.testing.json\" mocha --require ts-node/register 'src/test/**/*.ts'",
    "build": "tsc -p"
  },
```

I just added the ID to the `req.body` and only read it if `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'`. So I added this to the route:

```js
    const data: object = req.body;
    ...
    const id: string = !empty(data.id) && process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? data.id : null;
    delete data.id;

    const ref: any = !empty(id)
        ? db.collection('tickets').doc(id) 
        : db.collection('tickets');

    try {

        empty(id) ? await ref.add(data) : await ref.set(data);
        result.message = 'Ticket created';
        result.data = data;
        result.ok = true;
        return res.status(201).json(result);
    } catch(error) {
        result.message = 'Couldn\'t create ticket';
        result.error = error;
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).json(result);
    }
```